# Custom values for ReactiveSearch RangeSlider

Tags: elasticsearch, rangeslider, reactivesearch

I am trying to use the RangeSlider component of Reactivesearch and got stuck into setting the range value. I have a database with books and I want to use the RangeSlider for the publication year of the books.
I would like the start value to be the minimum year in database, and the end value to be the maximum year. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DynamicRangeSlider component of ReactiveSearch and use the prop `defaultSelected` if you are using version 2 or `defaultValue` if you are using version 3.